# Best methods for developing on/from a cloud server?

Tags: database, google-app-engine, amazon-web-services, cloud, server-administration

I recently landed myself on a project that, like most projects today, relies on multiple relational databases and also, like most projects today, relies on the flexibility and security of cloud computing.

I got into cloud services a little over a month ago and since then I've tackled the basics of most the services that Amazon Web Services offers but have only tested and deployed personal projects.

Now I will be working on a clients server and its a hefty instance, therefore I need to research the best method for developing a pre-existing application on a cloud server. Also bare in mind that the data stored in the databases is also being updated 'live'/dynamically.

I assume it's still good practise to take a local copy to work on? In that case, is the best method to download the whole server using ssh? If so, are there any alternatives? I feel that just downloading the whole server and setting it all back up bit by bit (including the data 'stream') will be very time consuming for such a big application connected to such big databases.

Is there something a little more elegant?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on a cloud environment you may have developement environment.

You may have a local repository but nothing  more than your IDE and your versionning tool.

All your service might be provided by the cloud and the most efficient way to test you code is to do it on a target Image.

personally ,I use  cloud foundry or IBM Bluemix with my git repository. I push directly the modifications  when i want to test.

Answer (score 0):

you can use cloud services,you dont have to think about server setup/services.you will just need a repository like git.
you can follow below sample link for getting started on configuration on bluemix:

https://hub.jazz.net/tutorials

https://www.facebook.com/ibmswg?ref=hl&ref_type=bookmark